# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Facebook Like Counter

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

I have the following script to get the amount of likes from a Facebook page:

```
$("#facebook-likes").each(function () {
  var container = $(this);
  var fburl = container.attr('rel');
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query',
    data: {
      query: 'SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="' + fburl + '"',
      format: 'json'
    }
  }).success(function (data) {
    container.text(data[0].like_count + ' Likes');
  });
});
```

When running the script I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'like_count' of undefined

I've searched the internet for a solution but I can't find one solving this problem. I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: data[0] is undefined.

Comment: Either use a debugger; set a break point at `container.text(data[0].like_count` and look at `data` to see what it is, or `console.log(data)` and see what data you're getting in the console. One way, or another `data[0]` is undefined. Generally, that implies that you do not have the right understanding of the `data` you are going to get back from your API call, or you are not performing a validity check on that `data` which you should be doing.

Comment: Are you aware "[As of August 8, 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried. To migrate your app, use the API Upgrade Tool to see the Graph API calls you can make instead.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)"

Comment: see my answer, that api call should not work at all anymore. use console.log(data) and you will most likely see an understandable error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL is deprecated, this is the correct API to get the likes of a Page:

```
https://graph.faebook.com/[page-id]?fields=fan_count
```

You can test it in the API explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=page-id%3Ffields%3Dfan_count&version=v2.7

Be aware that this needs an Access Token, so you should not do that client side with an App Access Token. You should also consider caching the result, not to hit API limits if there are a lot of users.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

It means that `data[0]` is `undefined` which means that you cannot access the `like_count` attribute.

Try to display the `data` object to see its attributes/elements you could display/use.

Comment: Been there.  I know how that goes.